# URL Query Retrofit 2

Tags: android, retrofit

I am designing a cryptocurrency tracker and this base URL will not work with specific data I need. I read my error is most likely caused by the API URL being called incorrectly.

Error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 
'java.lang.Object java.util.List.get(int)' on a null object reference
```

base URL

```
https://rest.coinapi.io/
```

http request

```
GET /v1/symbols?filter_symbol_id={filter_symbol_id}
```

My code

```
String BASE_URL = "https://rest.coinapi.io/";

@GET("v1/symbols")
Call<List<Coin>> getCoin(@Query("filter_symbol_id") String filter_symbol_id);
}
```

Code calling API

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
    setContentView (R.layout.activity_main);

    final ListView listView = findViewById (R.id.listView);

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder ()
            .baseUrl (Api.BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory (GsonConverterFactory.create ())
            .build ();

    Api api = retrofit.create (Api.class);

    Call<List<Coin>> call = api.getCoin ("filter_symbol_id");

    call.enqueue (new Callback<List<Coin>> () {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Coin>> call, 
Response<List<Coin>> response) {

            List<Coin> coin = response.body ();

            String[] coinName = new String[10];

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {


                coinName[i] = coin.get (i).getsymbol_id ();


                listView.setAdapter (
                        new ArrayAdapter<String> (
                                getApplicationContext (),
                                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                                coinName

                        )
                );

            }
        }


        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Coin>> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText (getApplicationContext (), t.getMessage (), 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();
        }
        });

    }

}
```

Coin.java

```
package com.dev20tx.android.cryptohero;

public class Coin {

private String symbol_id;


public Coin(String symbol_id) {
    this.symbol_id = symbol_id;


}

public String getsymbol_id() {
    return symbol_id;
}
}
```

I found many helpful stackoverflow posts that helped me fetch other data, but this one has me confused. Could someone point me in the right direction?

PROBLEM SOLVED: I used a different URL "v1/assets", which fixed the NullPointerException, updated my code across java files & it works.  For some reason the API v1/symbols is not currently working at coinapi.io

Comment: show more of your code and how you're calling it

Comment: Please post the code from where you are calling the api

Comment: @codyCaughlan Code is posted now

Comment: @Sreedev P R Code is posted now

Comment: what does the response JSON look like? can you post a sample response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing `api_key`

```
@GET("v1/symbols")
Call<List<Coin>> getCoin(@Query("filter_symbol_id") String filter_symbol_id, @Query("apikey") String apiKey);
```

For more info visit https://docs.coinapi.io/#authorization

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.  I updated it but still getting the same error.  I also posted my coin.java file to see if there is anything wrong there.

Comment: `https://rest.coinapi.io/v1/symbols/filter_symbol_id=FILTER_SYMBOL_ID&apikey=YOUR_IP_KEY` try this from browser

Comment: It gives me ""error": "You didn't specify API key or it is incorrectly formatted. You should do it in query string parameter `apikey` or in http header named `X-CoinAPI-Key`"...I ended up using the http v1/assets instead of v1/symbols and it works great now.  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The error must be in your `Coin` class. So please post `Coin.class`. I think the `NullPointerException` is because the `GSON` can't Serialize the `Coin` objects, may be `@SerializedName("")` is missing. Or else Show `Coin.class` code. (Remember `apikey` parameter is also missing, so the response will be `401 Unauthorized` but it doesn't cause any `NullPointerException`).

```
package com.dev20tx.android.cryptohero;

public class Coin {

@SerializedName("symbol_id") //replace with your response field.
private String symbol_id;


public Coin(String symbol_id) {
    this.symbol_id = symbol_id;
}

public String getsymbol_id() {
    return symbol_id;
}
}
```

Comment: I just posted it.  I also updated my apikey.  Thanks

Comment: Try the changes in `Coin.java`.